# RewriteRule based on file existence with another name

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We currently use an image resizer that was written in PHP. The resizing script takes advantage of caching, and writes the generated resized images to a cache directory (aptly named `cache/`).

The process is such that a rewritten URL, for example:
`domain.com/img/250x250/some-image.jpg`

Will be re-written to:
`domain.com/image.php?width=250&height=250&src=some-image.jpg&function=resizeCrop`

Inside `image.php`, we make a check to see whether a file matches the resize in the `cache/` dir. All cached images are stored with a name of `cachFunctionWidth_height_originalName`, so for the given example the generated image file inside `cache/` would be named `resizecrop250_250_some-image.jpg`

At the moment, we're utilizing PHP's [`fpassthru()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) function to output the file to the browser if it exists. If it doesn't we use a combination of GD functions and algorithms to output the file to the browser.

My question is whether it will be possible for us to bypass the `image.php` completely if a resized image exists in the `cache` directory using HTACCESS (it's a Linux server). Essentially, we need to check for a bastardized name form before serving rewriting.

For example, here's some pseudo-code of what we'd like to achieve, but I don't think it's possible:

- User requests file > domain.com/img/250x250/some-image.jpg
- Check if file `cache/resizecrop250_250_some-image.jpg` exists
- If it does, rewrite to `cache/resizecrop250_250_some-image.jpg`
- If it doesn't, rewrite to `domain.com/image.php?width=250&height=250&src=some-image.jpg&function=resizeCrop`

If this is not possible through HTACCESS, any other suggestions would also be welcome.

Comment: `we make a check to see whether a file matches the resize in the cache/` why isn't `/img/250x250/some-image.jpg` the cached file's location? using php instead of no-php is almost certainly a sub-optimal solution unless there's an unmentioned requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe using mod_rewrite it is possible. Consider following rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# check if constructed image name exists in cache directory    
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/resizecrop$1_$2_$3 -f
# exists, redirect to cache/constructed-image-file-name
RewriteRule ^img/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/([^.]+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ /cache/resizecrop$1_$2_$3 [L,NC]

# doesn't exist then forward to image.php with required query parameters
RewriteRule ^img/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/([^.]+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ /image.php?width=$1&height=$2&src=$3&function=resizeCrop [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a great solution and just what we were looking for!